# Why video hosted on vimeo is not played on some browsers and devices?

Tags: html, css, browser, vimeo, vimeo-player

I hosted my video on vimeo and try to access on my application. But On some browser such as google chrome it is played as per my expectation but on firefox it is not going to play.
below is the code whichy i did to play it.
HTML :

```
<div id="intro-video" class="modal">
    <div class="pull-right"><a class="btn-close"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i></a>
    </div>
    <p>Watch this short instructional video to learn how to get the most out of MDCapsule.</p>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/71276529?color=4a94d2" width="100%" height=300 frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And please find the image attach to this question for better undestanding.Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: This example is working in FF -> http://jsfiddle.net/NqecH/ From your screenshot I can see that you are wrapping it into popup. Can you add popup wrapper code and styles ?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I solved this problem by making http request to https.